# Caffe finetuning pretrain model, test accuracy doesn't increase to 0.9+

Tags: caffe

I am a new to caffe and I am experiencing a weird thing when I train my model. For tge same solver prototype, if I train without pre-train model, its test accuracy can increase to 0.9+, however if I finetune with a pre-train model, its accuracy fluctuate between 0.5-0.6. How can I solve the problem, making finetune model test accuracy increase up to 0.9?

Following is my command and configure file:

1 train:

./build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver_cmp.prototxt -gpu 0

2 finetune:

./build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver_cmp.prototxt --weights=pruned_sqznet.caffemodel -gpu 0

3 solver_cmp.prototxt

net: "pruned_sqznet.prototxt"

test_iter: 80

test_interval: 100

base_lr: 0.01

type: "Nesterov"

display: 40

max_iter: 100000

iter_size: 16 #global batch size = batch_size * iter_size

gamma: 0.0001

lr_policy: "poly"

power: 1.0 #linearly decrease LR

momentum: 0.9

weight_decay: 0.005

snapshot: 10000

snapshot_prefix: "examples/crowd/models/cmp_fine"

random_seed: 42

solver_mode: GPU

average_loss: 40

Comment: Could your model be overfitting without the pre-trained weights?

Comment: l don't know, my pre-traind model has been pruned, l finetune the pruned pre-trained model to recover predict test accuracy, buit it fail,  how should I do! thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "pruned"?